# As3 RotationX and RotationY blur the original image

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a quick question regarding RorationX, Y, Z

Whenever i have applied that, my image gets blured

_eventParent.getChildAt(1) is a Sprite.

Any reason why? and how can i stop this?

```
        _eventParent.getChildAt(1).rotationY = _differentX; 
        _eventParent.getChildAt(1).rotationX = _differentY;
```

Comment: Does your Sprite contain a bitmap and if so has the smoothing been set to true?

Comment: @crooksy88 i have a bitmap inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate a sprite, it gets automaGically associated bitmap buffers for fast manipulation with the rendering engine. There are solutions for that, which are not very effective but here is a 
[link to the best so far method.](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/blursol/)